# Simple localhost proxy for local development

Tags: http, proxy, routes

What is a good, lightweight http proxy I can use during development on my machine? I have to bring up two HTTP servers locally that should look as if they were one to the external user. We have a proper proxy setup for prod, but I would need something lightweight for development to test things.

Comment: what kind of proxy do you need ? Something with docker and nginx seems to be fast to build and a good choice.

Comment: I would be looking for whatever is the simplest, that can handle behavior like: for /some_path/* -> go to localhost:7001, for /other_path/* go to localhost:7002.

Comment: The first thing that come to my mind would be nginx

Comment: Thanks, I will start educating myself.